# Can I add options to dired-rsync?

Tags: dired

I recently installed `dired-rsync` which is exciting, but I immediately could not figure out how to add options when using it, like `-a` or `-u`, etc.   Is it possible to use such options and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, there is a customisation option `dired-rsync-options` for exactly this purpose. However just be aware that we have the default options of `-az --info=progress2` set so we can detect the percentage completion for the mode-line.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like the answer; however, such an option doesn't come up when I begin typing in the mini buffer.  The only option is `dired-rsync' and that is the sole completion.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, I needed to install something called 'dired-rsync-transient' from packages.  This seems to work.

Comment: hmm thats weird. It's defined in dired-rsync.el - how have you added it to your config?